# Naming cookies - best practices

Tags: php, cookies, naming-conventions

What should cookie names look like?

Should they be:

- lower_case
- CamelCase
- Underscore_Camel_Case
- UPPER_CASE

Or should they be something else?

Comment: Good question! Would upvote it if I had votes left.

Comment: @Pekka: I upvoted for you. I would upvote it too, but can only upvote once :(

Comment: @Bran, I upvoted for you since I get new votes in a few minutes anyways. Oh but I was gonna vote for this too... gosh darnit.

Comment: Thanks Jacob! That brings us a step forward. You didn't plan to upvote this question by any chance, did you? Because if you did, we'll need yet another volunteer!

Comment: Just in case, I wouldn't. So, here's my +1 for you guys. :)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

`appname_meaningfulname`

Comment: @Emanuil: To distinguish it from all the other cookies generated by other apps on the same domain.

Comment: @Emanuil Rusev, browser add-ons sometimes set cookies. I just learned this the hard way when my website picked up a cookie and got the data set by the user's add-on instead of the data set by my site.

Answer (score 8):

Keep in mind that this cookie is sent with every request, so imho, just use the smallest name you can, and document your code nicely.

Comment: This should not be a concern. Giving cookies descriptive names, as suggested in the accepted answer, should be preferred over saving a few bytes in every request (which itself is already ~800 bytes in size).

Answer (score 4):

It should be something that avoids naming conflicts with arbitrary _GET and _POST params you might be using, since _REQUEST wraps all three global arrays (!), with precedence depending on how your variables_order setting is set in php.ini. In other words, if you have a _COOKIE named "x" and a querystring param named "x", and you ask for $_REQUEST["x"], you get the cookie value when you might want/expect the GET param. This is especially problematic if your cookies are scoped to your website root "/", and not to the folder where they are consumed.

So I say, two best practices:

1. make sure you limit scope of your cookies to the path where they are read and written, (third argument of setcookie() method does this)
2. give your cookies some sort of cookie-specific naming convention. I suggest reverse website, like java namespaces, then ".".{appname}.".".{friendly cookie name camel cased}  So, if your site is www.testsite.com, and your app is foo, and your variable is "bar bar bar bar bar barann", it would be "com.testsite.foo.barBarBarBarBarBarann"

Comment: Have you seen some of these practices in a live website?

Answer (score 3):

I use whatever style the coding standards for the project call for.

Generally I prefer camelCase for naming schemes, but whichever one pays the bills is the one I'll go with.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you won't like my answer:

Don't use your own cookies but store data in server sessions. So you only need one cookie (to reference the session id) and how you name that plays no role.

Comment: That becomes messy with load balancers, as then the session should be stored in a database which isn't on the same host (or possibly even the same datacenter). Sometimes cookies are just fine.

Comment: @dotancohen can you provide some links regarding the issue you describe? thank you!

Comment: **"Don't use cookies"** sounds a bit puritanical; but I do like this attempt to keep things clean for the user.

Comment: securecookies can be used safely without any server-side session storage. They don't have to be huge (actually there's a limit of 4k which is quite modest) and avoids load-balancers and/or centralized DB lookups.

Comment: This is brilliant. There are tons of things that are kept in a database, and I don't see many people complaining about that