# Is it okay to name a cookie starting with a number?

Tags: php, cookies, rfc, specifications

I want to know if is it okay to name a cookie starting with a number. Actually, I've tested the following code using Apache2.2.21, PHP 5.3.8 and Chrome 19.0.1084.46:

```
setcookie('1test', 'a value'); 
if (isset($_COOKIE['1test'])) echo $_COOKIE['1test'];
```

It works just fine under these conditions, but what I want to know: **is there any spec or RFC that recommends not to do it?**

Comment: A similar question got [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2097857/1376657) as favourite answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see anything [in the specs](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc6265.html) that says you can't use a number as the first character in a cookie's name.